# Повтор команды alert () через определенное время

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли без обновления страницы, каждые 10 секунд, вызывать команду alert(Hi), и что бы на веб сайте, каждые 10 секунд выскакивало окошко с Hi. Если возможно, то как это делать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все возможно. Вопрос - зачем.

```js
function showAlert() {
  alert("Hi.");
  setTimeout(showAlert, 3000);
}
showAlert();
```

Comment: Необходимо отслеживать определенные данные с сайта (они меняются ), не обновляя его, ничего лучше чем это я не смог придумать, разве что можно вместо alert(), использовать console.log. Большое спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

```js
        function Alert() {
            alert('Hi');
        }
        setInterval(Alert, 10000);
```

Comment: Что будет с интервалом, если пользователь долго не закрывает диалог?

Comment: @Igor Так автор написал `без обновления страницы, каждые 10 секунд, вызывать команду alert(Hi)`. Если бы он написал, что если не нажата кнопка, то не выводить, или, если не нажата кнопка скрывать и снова выводить - это можно было бы легко реализовать.

Comment: Мне просто было интересно, накапливаются ли события интервала, пока открыт модальный диалог `alert`-а.

Comment: @Igor Ну да. ) По идее может много накопиться, что потом замучаешься закрывать.